# Adding non-spatial tables from an ArcGIS Online Hosted Feature Service into QGIS using ArcGIS REST Servers

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, feature-service

I have successfully connected to an ArcGIS Online Account using the details outlined [here](https://north-road.com/2022/09/16/securely-accessing-arcgis-online-agol-and-enterprise-arcgis-portal-sites-through-qgis-2022-update/#agol_register)

However, I cannot access the non-spatial layers i.e. Tables

Does anyone know how to access AGOL feature service tables from within QGIS?

QGIS Version: 3.28.10-Firenze